# Disallow users from adding Leads to inactive Campaigns

Tags: permissions, leads

I'm trying to find a way to disallow users from adding Leads to campaigns that are inactive. My current workaround is through an Apex trigger that removes a lead from any inactive campaign when the lead is edited, but it would be great to disallow users from adding leads to inactive campaigns up front. Is there an explicit way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use a trigger to throw an error when it is created with an inactive campaign.

Comment: Is this possible to do on a Lead that already exists?

Comment: Well, what is your exact use case?  Does the lead already exist and then someone tries to attach it to a campaign?  Or are you talking about trying to go back and catch all the ones that already skipped this criteria?  Giving us enough detail lets us know what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I don't want users to be able to add an existing lead to an inactive campaign. Ideally, users wouldn't be able to access/see inactive campaigns, but I'm fine with throwing an error if it's added to an inactive campaign.

Comment: This is definitely something that can be done in a trigger.  You would need to query for the related Campaigns and check the status.  If it's inactive you can do something like yourLead.CampaignId.addError('Inactive Campaign');

Comment: How  would I add that error if CampaignId is not an accessible field on the lead? I tried adding that code and received an error, 'Invalid field campaignid for SObject Lead at line 33 column 25'.

Comment: And of course if it can be done in a validation rule, that's the best place.  Yea the actual field name is weird I guess.  I can't find the actual fieldname for the campaign even though the admin setup says it's there.  I'd have to look a little harder online to find it but since you found your answer I see no reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A validation rule should work:
(ISNEW()&&NOT(Campaign.IsActive)) || (ISCHANGED(CampaignId) && NOT(Campaign.IsActive))